# Android ICS MediaPlayer crashes only on variables meant for simultaneous playback

Tags: java, android, crash, media-player, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have two types of playback of MediaPlayer in two different apps. One is a single variable that waits until it is finished to play the next word/sound effect. This seems to work fine. The other is a set of up to 4 MediaPlayer variables that play simultaneously. This works in 2.3.3 and seems to work on a 4.0.3 virtual device, but on my TF101 it crashes in both apps.

On a wrong touch, playse('oops') would be called.

```
public void playse(String ss){
    MediaPlayer tempse;

    if(tse1 == null){tempse = tse1;}
    else{if(tse2 == null){tempse = tse2;}
    else{if(tse3 == null){tempse = tse3;}
    else{if(tse4== null){tempse = tse4;}}}}

   if(ss == "oops"){ tempse =  MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.seoops); tempse.start();}
}
```

In the main loop of the app the 4 variables are handled like this:

```
        if(tse1 != null){ if(tse1.isPlaying()== false){tse1.release(); tse1=  null;} }

        if(tse2 != null){ if(tse2.isPlaying()== false){tse2.release(); tse2=  null;} }

        if(tse3 != null){ if(tse3.isPlaying()== false){tse3.release(); tse3=  null;} }  

        if(tse4 != null){ if(tse4.isPlaying()== false){tse4.release(); tse4=  null;} }
```

Comment: Your question really doesn't explain what you're trying to do. But aside from that, never use `==` as a comparison for `Strings` it can cause unpredictable results. Change `if(ss == "oops")` to `if (ss.equals("oops"))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can abbreviate that

```
MediaPlayer tempse;
if(tse1 == null){tempse = tse1;}
else{if(tse2 == null){tempse = tse2;}
else{if(tse3 == null){tempse = tse3;}
else{if(tse4== null){tempse = tse4;}}}}
```

to

```
MediaPlayer tempse = null;
```

Maybe you should change the `==` to `!=`

That's the only thing that I can see without knowing what error you get.

Comment: I was trying to allow for simultaneous sounds. I thought I was using a reference which would point to one of the 4 ongoing sounds. Threw some code at it, and when it worked in 2.3.3 I moved on. Think the thing for me to do is just remove all the tse1-4, and load/play the files without worrying about having a variable to check later on. I think the companion queued sound code had me thinking it would be more complex. Thanks. Just strange that it worked in 2.3.3 and seemingly in the virtual device, but not on my TF101 with 4.0.3

Comment: It would seem that soundpool is a better way of handling multiple sounds at the same time. Even with the other code removed, the debugger shows lots of issues and the audio quality declines if sounds played quickly when using MediaPlayer.

Comment: I think I initially went with MediaPlayer because I was working on the queued multiple sounds version and it seemed easier(or even just possible?) to determine if a sound was still playing and then move on. Is it possible to determine if a sound is currently playing using SoundPool?

Comment: Audio playback relies a lot on how good the hardware (and drivers etc) is at that. You can get audio dropouts even if you do it correct, but that depends mostly on the device. Regarding `Soundpool`: Idk if you can find out what sound is playing. Check the docs. Maybe there are callbacks or you can read out the status.